# Nautilus is slow if a lot of images are in a directory

Tags: nautilus, performance, photo-management, nice

I have 400 images in a directory. I look at the directory with nautilus.

The first time I open the directory it is very slow. I have a modern laptop with 4 cores and plenty of RAM.

My use case:

- open directory containing a lot of images
- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> to make the images larger
- I want to sort the images to some directories, or delete some images.

Result:

- Nautilus is unusably slow. I walked away from the laptop to do different stuff, some time later it was usable.
- Nautilus has 104% CPU in top.
- Low "wait" value in top: Disk is not the bottleneck

Guess:

- Nautilus creates the thumbnails of all images, without nice-level.
- But all thumbnails are not needed at once. I just looked at the first 10 images.
- Nautilus should prefer user input to background thumbnail creation, since user response is more important.
- Multicores hang around idle.

My conclusion:

- if Nautilus would use all cores and with a nice value for background stuff, the user would have better responsiveness and the background job would be quicker.

Question: Is there anything I can do to solve this?

Maybe a configuration which can I set, or create a bug report for the developers?

Comment: I  updated the question: Disk is not the bottleneck.

Comment: Works fine for me with a directory of 682 images in Nautilus 3.8, each 4MB+ in size... which version of nautilus are you using, and have you tried filing a bug report? Also, are there any processes other than nautilus using resources (i think most thumbnailers are separate)

Comment: No other process was doing noticeable load (watched it with top). I use nautilus 3.10.1 (Default of Ubuntu 14-04). There was only a one process (nautilus) active, thus the thumbnailing must be in a single process.

Comment: You tried it? Have you done ctrl++ do enlarge the images to the most possible size? I tried it in a different directory and it was the same.